# Server ip with multiple domains / but only 1 user on /etc/passwd

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, passwd

I have access on a server that is running multiple domains on it, but when i check the /etc/passwd file i see only 1 user available ? is it mean that each user have his own linux instalation ? virtual machine or what ?

**Example :**
(domain1.com) and (domain2.com) and (domain3.com) they all have the same remote ip address but when reading the /etc/passwd file of (domain1.com) i see only the user of (domain1.com) not (domain2.com) and (domain3.com) etc..

Can someone explain to me ? Thanks.

**Example of /etc/passwd :**

```
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
adm:x:3:4:adm:/var/adm:/sbin/nologin
lp:x:4:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/sbin/nologin
sync:x:5:0:sync:/sbin:/bin/sync
shutdown:x:6:0:shutdown:/sbin:/sbin/shutdown
halt:x:7:0:halt:/sbin:/sbin/halt
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin
games:x:12:100:games:/usr/games:/sbin/nologin
ftp:x:14:50:FTP User:/var/ftp:/sbin/nologin
dbus:x:81:81:System message bus:/:/sbin/nologin
sshd:x:74:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin
rpc:x:32:32:Rpcbind Daemon:/var/lib/rpcbind:/sbin/nologin
nscd:x:28:28:NSCD Daemon:/:/sbin/nologin
named:x:25:25:Named:/var/named:/sbin/nologin
dovecot:x:97:97:Dovecot IMAP server:/usr/libexec/dovecot:/sbin/nologin
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
cpaneleximfilter:x:203:203::/var/cpanel/userhomes/cpaneleximfilter:/usr/local/cpanel/bin/noshell
mail:x:8:12:mail:/var/spool/mail:/sbin/nologin
postfix:x:89:89::/var/spool/postfix:/sbin/nologin
mailman:x:209:209::/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman:/usr/local/cpanel/bin/noshell
mailnull:x:47:47:Exim:/var/spool/mqueue:/bin/false
mysql:x:27:27:MySQL Server:/var/lib/mysql:/bin/false
nobody:x:99:99:Nobody:/:/sbin/nologin
postgres:x:26:26:PostgreSQL Server:/var/lib/pgsql:/bin/bash
domain1:x:1086:1089::/home/domain1:/usr/local/cpanel/bin/noshell
```

Comment: Users and domains have nothing to do with each other. The fact that one of the users is named `domain1` may be a coincidence or may be deliberate, but I don't know the motivation of whoever or whatever created that user. Likewise, users and Linux installations have nothing to do with each other. You can have a Linux installation with zero non-system users, or with hundreds of them.

Comment: @berndbausch Ok i see but each user in /etc/passwd need to have his private documentROOT /home/domain1/public_html/ for example. and my server have many domains, why only 1 user listed on /etc/passwd ?

Comment: A user doesn't have a document root. A user has a home directory. Document roots are properties of web sites, not users. If you have several web sites on the same server, they are sometimes called virtual hosts (this is an Apache term, I think). They are not configured in /etc/passwd, but in the web server's configuration files, for example `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. Often, each virtual host has its own domain, although that is not required either: Several virtual hosts can use the same domain but different ports.

Comment: To further clarify, `/etc/passwd` has nothing to do with Apache, domains, or web servers on same or different domains. Your web server configuration is what tells Apache what domains (IP, port, etc) to respond to and how to respond. From Apache's perspective, you can have an entirely different set of "user" than those in `/etc/passwd`. The Apache documentation has plenty of information about how it works.

Comment: As for the question asked... It looks to me like the server is running a virtual webhost where the hosting company set it up so _you_ can only see a "fake" `/etc/passwd` file for your hosting account, and not any other customers--even if you are really a single person with multiple domain accounts.